# what is the research strategy to adopt to compile my notes into a scientific article for a conference?

Tags: publications, research-process, independent-researcher

Suppose I read multiple scientific articles related to a specific topic, what are the kind and the research strategy to adopt in order to compile my note-taken into a scientific article for a conference ?

Comment: it is related to "audio forensics" ... so "survey article" may be the one ?

Comment: survey article is one possibility , is there other please  ?

Comment: A conference is likely looking for a contribution with new research. If you have read articles and taken notes, that is not the same thing at all.

Comment: I know :) maybe I didn"t express myself well, by taking note and reading specific articles related to the field, I am wondering if there is an alternative articles such as "review article" in the field ...

Comment: It sounds like what you really require is general advice and guidance on how to begin writing and publishing in your field.  This is the sort of thing which can be much better given by an individual mentor who knows you personally — e.g. your supervisor, if you’re a student.

Comment: I am actually an independent researcher... Newbie level

Answer (score 2):

Conferences generally publish novel research: papers that present new findings, ideas or techniques. Research in academia does not mean the same thing as in high school. So if all you have is notes on other papers, that's not publishable.

The only real exception to this is survey papers, where you give an extremely comprehensive overview and framing of  research in a given topic. But these tend to be long, so they're usually in journals, and are usually written by experts who have been involved with the developments they're writing about.